# Python, datetime and csv columns auto visualization

Tags: python, csv, automation

In a .csv document I have different columns, one for each day of the week, that I would visualize in a single tkinter's treeview column.
I have no idea how to do it, so how can I code an automatic print for the right column for the current day? (I mean, if it's monday, I would my script print the column referred to monday, on tuesday print tuesday's column and so on...).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged `automation`?

Comment: Because I want that it changes without human intervention